# Default parameter value is good practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I have a controller method called `GetCustomer(int id=0)`

This smells weird in my opinion, but was already here, and I'm wondering if this is a good practice!

I would rather in this case use nullable type!

Comment: use of nullable type is better option.

Comment: tbh whether you use a default parameter or not should be decided by the business logic. what are you trying to do and does it justify using a default parameter. would it be better just to throw an exception and return a 404?

Comment: What URL does that map to? Is it `/customers/id`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman your data layer can easily have entity with 0 id.

Comment: I sit on the fence with this, part of me likes that it has "a" value, so all calls to things will work, nothings gonna barf or need a ton of "is null" checking wrapped round it.. at the same time.. if you didnt send the required parameters, why should you allow the code?

Comment: @teo *what* data layer?

Comment: A default parameter value *by itself* is neither good nor bad practice.  *How the method uses this parameter* is the more important piece of what you're asking.

Comment: @PatrickHofman that situated in controller.

Comment: I finally found out what was the reason, and it was really silly! because of uinit test...so someone hacked the method to have default value to "fix" an unit test...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that action maps onto `GET /customers/id`, making the `id` optional (by means of a parameter with a default value *or* a nullable type) is bad API design.

Traditionally, `GET /customers` maps onto an action that retrieves all existing customers, not onto `GET /customers/0`. You can also simply not support calls to `GET /customers`.

Comment: Is not the case, we always get in this method only one customer, it's by id, so that why I don't understand why using 0 as default value!